# Close a FileHandle if WeakReference is garbage collected

Tags: java, garbage-collection, weak-references, filehandle, randomaccessfile

I have a class of the following structure:

```
public class RandomMatrixIndex implements IIndex {

    private final HashMap<Long, Long> index;
    private RandomAccessFile rand;

    // constructor and methods.
}
```

In the constructor the RandomAccessFile rand is opened.
In another class i created a hashmap:

```
 private final HashMap<String, WeakHashMap<String, IIndex>> _MATRIX_MAP;
 _MATRIX_MAP.put(....);
```

The map contains a mapping to a IIndex interface which is implemented by the class above. If I put the RandomMatrixIndex in the map, the reference could be garbage collected and I cant close the RandomAccessFile properly.

Now my question. How do i close the RandomAccessFile if the reference to the WeakHashMap is lost? DO I have to include a finalizer in the RandomMatrixIndex constructor? OR is the filehandle closed automatically. (pls forgive if this is poor coding style)

Thanx alot!

Comment: On garbage collection the RandomAccessFile.finalize is called amd everything is fine.

Comment: So i can just override that? Or do nothing at all?= :D

Comment: I personally would close as soon as possible, but yes, you probably need not do anything.

Comment: As far as I see, `RandomAccessFile` doesn't close itself in `finalize()`. In that case, you should do it yourself from `RandomMatrixIndex.finalize()`.

Comment: I checked the source code, @doublep is right. Sorry; I know sequential file I/O closes in finalize.

Comment: Thank you both very much :)